# Array must be Initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

```
class LUT {
public :
vector <string> Allgate_name;
vector<vector<double> > Cload_vals;
vector<vector<double> > Tau_in_vals;
vector<double [7][7] > All_delays;
vector<double [7][7] > All_slews;
void assignarrays(string);
};
```

The above code shows that I am declaring a vector of 7x7 array. But when I try to push a 7x7 array into this vector I am getting the following errors.

"array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer"
"invalid array assignment"

The intialization of the array that I am pushing into this vector is simply this.

```
double NAND_loadtable_d [7][7];
```

Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: That is not initialization, that is only a declaration

Comment: show the code you use to "push" 7x7 array to the vector.

Comment: Show us the code that actually fails. Better yet, show a [mcve](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector::push_back` requires that the element type is [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) (when you pass an lvalue such as `NAND_loadtable_d`). Plain old arrays are not CopyAssignable.

Instead of an array, you could use a class that wraps a member array. Luckily, the standard library provides such wrapper for you: `std::vector<std::array<std::array<double, 7>, 7>>` instead.

Answer (score -4):

As UnholySheep has written you must initialize and not only declare the variable NAND_loadtable_d:

```
double NAND_loadtable_d [][] = new double[7][];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
   NAND_loadtable_d[i] = new double[7];
}
```

Comment: Using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) might be a (better?) recommendation. Also using [aggregate intialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) is probably preferable here as well.

Comment: I don't think this can answer the OP's question properly because the core part of his/her question is asking how to *push* an array to `std::vector`, NOT how to *initialize* an array. The proper answer should be delayed 'till we know how the OP's approaching for that matter.